# Merge 2 arrays of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How do you merge array1 and 2?

**array1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => bob
        [id] => 84569354306
        [contacts] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
        )
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => jill
        [id] => 456745742
        [contacts] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
        )
    )
)
```

**array2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => bob
        [id] => 84569354306
        [pid] => 1
        [lang] => eng;
        [location] =>
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => jill
        [id] => 456745742
        [pid] => 2
        [lang] => eng;
        [location] =>
    )
)
```

**Result array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => bob
        [id] => 84569354306
        [pid] => 1
        [lang] => eng;
        [location] =>
        [contacts] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
        )
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => jill
        [id] => 456745742
        [pid] => 2
        [lang] => eng;
        [location] =>
        [contacts] => Array
        (
            [0] => none
        )
    )
)
```

I've tried an `array_merge()` which seems to add objects next to each other in the array rather than merging the objects.

I'm pretty sure [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523017/php-how-to-merge-an-array-of-objects-with-an-array-of-arrays) is similar to what I need, but I'm having difficulty with the simple foreach loop.

Comment: Function [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) may be useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of doing it:

```
function merge_values(){
    $list = func_get_args();
    while( count( $list ) > 1 ){
        $array1 = array_shift( $list );
        $array2 = array_shift( $list );

        $merged_array = $array1;
        foreach( $array2 as $key => $value ){
            $merged_array[$key] = array_merge( (array)$value, (array)$merged_array[$key] );
            if( is_object( $value ) || is_object( $array1[$key] ) ){
                $merged_array[$key] = (object)$merged_array[$key];
            }
        }

        array_unshift( $list, $merged_array );
    } 
    return current( $list );
}

$merged = merge_values( $array1, $array2 );
```

Comment: I was going to upvote your other function. This one wraps everything in an extra array.

Comment: @rrrfusco I made a mistake when removing the recursion. It should return a  single array now

Answer (score 8):

You can cast the two objects to array and then re-cast back to an object. The general syntax is:

```
$merged = (object)array_merge_recursive((array)$firstObj, (array)$secondObj);
                              ^
                              | note the recursive in your case
```

Also, if you are using objects like that maybe you should simply stick to array. It has very little to no sense to do something like that with objects

### With multiple items

If you have multiple items you simply need to wrap up my script inside a loop:

```
function myCustomMerge($array1, $array2) {
   assert('count($array1) == count($array2)');
   $result = array();
   foreach($array1 as $k=>$v) {
    $item = array_merge_recursive((array)$array1[$k], (array)$array2[$k]);
    $result[]=$item; // use (object)$item if you need objects
   }
   return $result;
}
```

### Solution without casting

If you prefer not to cast back and forth between array and object you can use `get_object_vars()`:

```
$obj2props = get_object_vars($obj2);
foreach ($obj2props as $prop => $value) {
    $obj1->$prop = $value;
}
return $obj;
```

Comment: Given the sub array (contacts) shouldn't `array_merge_recursive` be used?

Comment: Would you change your approach if each array had multiple objects?

Comment: I added another object to the question. I'm assuming I add a loop to your code.

Comment: It would help. My loops put everything in one object.

Comment: Your casting examples/function are helpful, however the result has the same problem as my previous comment. Omar is closer so far.