# How to merge these array object by name key?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I need to merge the objects in an array that is grouped by name so that for each name, i return the name with "forecast" and "actuals" as part of the same object.How can I merge objects in laravel? "forecast" and "actuals" have come from 2 separate DB queries of the same table.

```
Collection {#464 
  #items: array:3 [
    "Peters Sow" => Collection {#459 
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Peters Sow"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "actuals" => 1
        ]
        1 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Peters Sow"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "forecast" => 1
        ]
      ]
    }
```

So that it can be like this with forecast and actuals as one under the name Peters Sow.

```
Collection {#464 
  #items: array:3 [
    "Peters Sow" => Collection {#459 
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Peters Sow"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "actuals" => 1
          "forecast" => 1
        ]
```

Comment: Try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226507/merge-2-arrays-of-objects-in-php/28226533

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mapWithKeys collection method will be able to achieve this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-mapwithkeys